# Use Windows 7 taskbar features in VS 2008 with MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-7, taskbar

Is it possible to use the new taskbar Windows 7 features in Visual Studio 2008, with MFC?
I know it is possible in VS 2010 and in VS2008 using WTL, But what about in VS 2008, is it possible to update MFC to v10?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to update MFC to the new version. Look into the `ITaskbarList3` COM interface; by catching a "TaskbarButtonCreated" registered window message, you can get the HWND of the taskbar button and create an instance of ITaskbarList3 to manipulate it with.

Sorry I don't have any good links on it handy, but that should be enough to get you started on Google (that's how we found it in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily copy 2010's MFC to 2008 but you sure can check the sources and crate your own classes that work under 2008.